# Populating an array of chars with strings dynamically

Tags: c, arrays, char

I'm new to C and i'm trying to store some strings inside a 2D array of chars.Here's what i have:

```
char strArray[100][100];
char input[100];
scanf("%s",&input);
strArray[i] = input; //this is where i get the incompatible types assignment error
```

As shown in the comment i get an `incompatible types in assignment` error.Do i need to use an array of `char *strArray[100][100]` ? Aren't `strArray` and `input` both of the same type (char [])? The one's 1D and the other is 2D obviously but i just didn't specify the 2nd dimension in the assignment since each string is stored in a new line. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `scanf("%s",&input);` -> `scanf("%s",input);` , `strArray[i] = input;` -> `strcpy(strArray[i], input);`

Comment: @Osiris that's the same thing right? the array works as a pointer but & works too right?

Comment: `input` decays to a pointer to `char` while `&input` is a pointer to `char[100]`. So it is not the same, and `%s` expects a pointer to `char`.

Comment: Oh i see, and as for the strcpy() function, is that the only way for this "procedure" to be done? Can it also be done with pointers?

Comment: You can loop over the array and copy it element wise. Or you can use `memcpy`. You can not copy arrays with the `=` operator.

Comment: @Osiris understood, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to use `strcpy()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char strArray[100][100];
    char input[100];
    scanf("%s", input);
    strcpy(strArray[0], input);
}
```

But never, really: never! use `scanf()` with `"%s"` without limiting the number of characters to read (field width):

```
 scanf("%99s", input);
```

Comment: That's an awesome tip, i had no idea i could limit the number of chars that the user can enter by specifying a number between % and s within scanf. Awesome

Answer (score 0):

In C, you cannot assign arrays in the sense of `char input1[100], input2[100]; input1 = input2`.  You can just copy the contents using, for example, `strcpy` for strings or `memcpy` for arbitrary memory chunks.

So you'd have to write `strcpy(strArray[i],input)`, provided that `i` is an integral value between `0` and `99` in your case.

Further, you'll have to omit the `&` in `scanf("%s",&input)` (i.e. write `scanf("%s",input)`), because `input` already decays to a pointer to char.

Answer (score 0):

You can use strcpy() to copy each char in input to strArray[i]. In this case you would use

```
strcpy(strArray[i], input);
```